# limit of modulus of z over z approach infinity in complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

I am solving $$\lim_{z \rightarrow \infty} \frac{|z|}{z}$$, for now I have
\begin{align*}
\lim_{z \rightarrow \infty} \frac{|z|}{z} &= \lim_{z \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{z\bar{z}}}{z} \\
&=\lim_{z \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{\frac{\bar{z}}{z}} \\
&=\sqrt{\frac{e^{-i\theta}}{e^{i\theta}}} \\
&=e^{-i\theta}
\end{align*}
Does this looks right? Thanks.

Comment: There is no limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks right, as a start.  Looks actually like the limit doesn't exist, since by taking $z=re^{i\theta}$ and letting $r\to \infty$ we get different limits for different $\theta$.